# c# error "Procedure 'spReturnLastRowNoteID' expects param '@noteid', which was not supplied." though I don't have input parameter in sp

Tags: c, ado.net

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spReturnLastRowNoteID   
(@noteid int OUTPUT)    
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT @noteid = NoteID
FROM NoteTable
WHERE NoteID = IDENT_CURRENT('NoteTable')
   RETURN @noteid`
```

I don't think there is a problem in my sp and code but I'm not sure why i'm getting the error:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();
   string sqlSearchCommand = "spReturnLastRowNoteID";
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlSearchCommand, connection);
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   SqlParameter noteid = command.Parameters.Add("@noteid", SqlDbType.Int);
   noteid.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   lastnoteid = (int)command.Parameters["@noteid"].Value;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the parameters direction to Output.

```
noteid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```